# How to dispatch or map response to requested threads without using any webserver?

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I'm creating some 10 threads and these threads will send request to the JMS. I have receiver that will match the correlation ID from the response to the passed correlation ID if it matches then that response has to match to the requested thread. For example if *thread A* makes a request then the response should dispatch to the *thread A* not for some other threads. How to achieve this in Java standalone application?

Answer (score 0):

Use a map of String and Thread, let that string be your corelation id. Have a common receiver, from there map.get(corellationID).doStuff(message).

Comment: David when i do map.get(corelationId) which one i have to get thread instance/thread name/thread id i mean what to put in the map. key is corelation id and value is thread name/id/thread instance. if value is thread id / thread name is it possible to access that particular thread. if yes how to access.. thanks